# Sprite changes colour when imported into Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, graphics, sprites, color

I create some simple geometrical shapes in Inkscape, then export it to PNG and import into Unity.

Positive example:
I make a rectangle of colour hsva(0, 0, 32, 255), export it as a 32x32 PNG image and import to Unity. Then I put it into the scene. When I check its rendered colour with a probe tool it's perfectly correct: hsva(0, 0, 32, 255).

Negative (problematic) example:
I create a **right triangle** of colour **hsva(0, 0, 32, 255)**, export it as a 32x32 PNG image. Effect: half of the image is transparent and the triangle edge is "anti-aliased", but the main triangle's area in the PNG file still conserves its original colour.

[image]

Then I import it into Unity and I put it into the same scene and check its rendered colour with a probe tool. It's actually **hsva(299, 8, 33, 255)** - very dark purple, but still distinguishable from the (0, 0, 32, 255).

What am I doing wrong? Why is the rendered colour of the sprite different?
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help  :)

PD

Adding my import settings, as requested in on of the comments (now I'm experimenting with larger images 512x512, but the effect is the same):
[image]

Comment: A few questions, Have you opened the png's with another image editting tool and verified the color values are indeed correct after exporting?  Are you using the default sprite settings when importing? Are you using the point filter?

Comment: Have you tried manipulating the shader of the auto-created game objects (when you drag the sprite into the scene)? If you go with standard shaders, the sprites might be affected by the scene's lighting settings.

Comment: Yes, verified in IrfanView that the colour is correct. The import setting for the two images are exactly the same.

Comment: Can you show us your texture import settings? Specifically the compression mode and "Alpha is transparency" flags may be relevant here.

Comment: Added the import settings. My in-scene object uses default sprite material.

Comment: I've just checked the lighting settings, but noticed nothing unusual. Environment Lighting / Source: Color hsv(0, 0, 255).

Comment: I notice you're using DXT5 compression for the triangle, which has reduced colour precision (5,6,5 bits of RGB respectively, or a 1/3:2/3 blend of two such colours). Are you using the same compression for your positive test case?

Comment: @DMGregory, that's it! I've "broken" the size of the sprite so that no DXT5 compression is applied and the colour is correct now. For the positive case, the BC7 compression has been automatically applied, although all the other settings are the same. I suppose it has something to do with the shape of the sprite?

Comment: @Ismael You could also just change the compression type used. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbtj3.png

Comment: Thanks, in the end, that was so easy! :)
 
@DMGregory Can you answer the question so that I officially mark your answer as correct and close the thread? ;)

Comment: I didn't answer, I just asked what apparently turned out to be a fruitful question. ;) Feel free to post your own answer explaining what you did to solve the problem. Answering & accepting your own posts is totally OK here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @DMGregory and @Draco18s for help with this one!

The problem turned out to be the compression algorithm which Unity automatically applied for the imported image. The DXT5 compression reduced colour precision, provoking the subtle change in the rendered colour of the sprite.

The solution to the problem was changing Compression Quality from "Normal Quality" to "High Quality" in the default import settings for the image.

[image]

This could be also solved by explicitly overriding the compresison algorithm in the build-specific settings of the image, selecting BC7 compression algorithm for instance.

[image]